# Azure storage queue - Cosmos DB output - error handling

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage-queues

We have an Azure js function that does some operations and then outputs to trigger a storage queue. The storage queue output inserts into Cosmos DB. Our Cosmos DB has a certain number of RUs available and during a traffic spike RUs will be exceeded. In this case it seems the db insert will fail with a 429 and need to be retried. Since the insert is handled as an "output" of the storage queue we don't know how to handle errors since our code will never see the error directly.

I've read briefly about "poison queues" but don't think I fully understand. If the operation above fails (after 5 attempts?) will the item automatically go into a newly created poison queue? Does it make sense to update our storage queue function to attempt to process items from the poison queue in addition to normal operations?

Queue Storage sample code:

```
module.exports = function(context, myQueueItem) {
    context.bindings.outputDocument = myQueueItem;
    context.done(); //insert happens here?
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, by default after 5 retries the message would get put into the poison queue. you can create another function to listen to that queue (doesn't really make sense to use the same function) or process those messages during off peak hours with some sort of scheduled trigger + script.

Comment: Useful link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/poison-message-handling